Transforming the reduced sextic $x^6+x^2+ax+b$ into a quintic
The Bring-Jerrard quintic: $$x^5+x = a$$
For $a≠0$. After some change we get: $$\frac x a = a^{-4/5}\left(1- \frac x a\right)^{1/5}$$
Expanding the RHS using binomial theorem because $\frac x a = \frac 1 {1+x^4}$ and $0\lt\frac 1 {1+x^4}\lt 1$  results in:$$\frac x a = a^{-4/5}\left(1+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{1/5}{k}\left(\frac {-x} a\right)^k\right)$$
Expressing the infinite series explicitly and rearranging the terms yields the following expression: $$1-(c_1+a^{4/5})\frac x a - c_2\left(\frac x a\right)^2 - c_3\left(\frac x a\right)^3 - c_4\left(\frac x a\right)^4-\dots=0$$
We use $\left(\frac x a\right)^5 = a^{-4}(1- \frac x a)$ repeatedly to eliminate $(\frac x a)^5$ and higher power terms, resulting in a quartic in $\frac x a$ as below: $$K_4\left(\frac x a\right)^4+K_3\left(\frac x a\right)^3+K_2\left(\frac x a\right)^2+K_1\frac x a+K_0=0$$
Where: $$K_0=1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^m} {a^{4m}} \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n \binom{m-1}{n} \binom{1/5}{4m+n+1}$$ $$K_1=-a^{4/5}+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^m} {a^{4(m-1)}} \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n \binom{m-1}{n} \binom{1/5}{4m+n-3}$$ $$K_2=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^m} {a^{4(m-1)}} \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n \binom{m-1}{n} \binom{1/5}{4m+n-2}$$ $$K_3=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^m} {a^{4(m-1)}} \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n \binom{m-1}{n} \binom{1/5}{4m+n-1}$$ $$K_4=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^m} {a^{4(m-1)}} \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n \binom{m-1}{n} \binom{1/5}{4m+n}$$
which converges for $$|a|\gt1$$ and choose out roots of the quartic so that $$0\lt \frac x a \lt1$$
Edit: I forgot about the case where a is complex which could make $\frac 1 {1+x^4}$ not in $[0,1] $ but one could use the quartic and choose out suitable x that satisfy the original quintic
Question: using transformation similar to the one above for Bring-Jerrard quintic, is it possible to transform the reduced sextic $x^6+x^2+ax+b=0$ into a quintic?

There is a fairly related discussion here. You may need to solve a high degree equation for the transformation.

@ТymaGaidash٠ I added the answer to this question. Hope you can check if it's correct

Since it has been several days and there is no answer, I guess it is ok to do it myself. To transform the reduced sextic $$x^6+x^2+ax+b=0$$ to the quintic
$$K_5x^5+K_4x^4+K_3x^3+K_2x^2+K_1x+K_0=0$$ is done in 2 steps
$\mathbf{Step\,1}$: Rearrange the reduced sextic so that the LHS is a quintic and the RHS is an infinite series $$x^5+x+a=-b/x$$ $$⇒x^5+x+a=b\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x+1)^k$$
$\mathbf{Step\,2}$: Reduce the RHS into another quintic via it's characteristic polynomial
We have the characteristic polynomial: $$x^6=-x^2-ax-b$$
it can be rewritten as: $$(x+1)^6=6(x+1)^5-15(x+1)^4+20(x+1)^3-16(x+1)^2+(-a+8)(x+1)+(a-b-2)$$ Define $c_0=a-b-2,c_1=-a+8,c_2=-16,c_3=20,c_4=-15,c_5=6$
Thus the equation simplify to: $$x^5+x+a=b[D_5(x+1)^5+D_4(x+1)^4+D_3(x+1)^3+D_2(x+1)^2+D_1(x+1)+D_0]$$ where $$D_k=1+\sum_{n=5-k}^5\frac{c_{n-5+k}}{\prod_{l=n}^5 1-c_l}$$ the condition for $D_k$ is $a\neq7,a-b\neq3$
Example 1: $x^6+x^2+3x+2=0$ after transforming we obtain: $$x^5+x+3=2(−0.0000048374613002(x+1)^5+3.73967685759(x+1)^4−2.79674922601(x+1)^3+4.13684210526(x+1)^2+0.0125(x+1)+1.2)$$ which has roots $x\approx-0.814401\pm0.27252i$ that is close to the roots of the original equation
Example 2: $x^6+x^2+9x+13=0$ after transforming we obtain: $$x^5+x+9=13(0.00000276426360024(x+1)^5+3.73931888545(x+1)^4−2.80089009288(x+1)^3+4.20855263158(x+1)^2+1.275(x+1)+2.2)$$ which has roots $x\approx-1.19644\pm0.496448i$ that is also close to the roots of the original equation
Example 3: $x^6+x^2+4x+2=0$ after transforming we obtain: $$x^5+x+4=2(−0.0000128998968008(x+1)^5+3.73962848297(x+1)^4−2.79736842105(x+1)^3+4.15(x+1)^2+0.2(x+1)+1)$$ which has roots $x=-1$ that is the roots of the original equation and $x\approx-0.59982$ that is close to the roots of the original equation
the link where i compute all of these: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zkpyvhmjze
$\mathbf{How\,I\,come\,up\,with\,the\,method\,for\,D_k}$:
Assume the infinite series $$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m$$ and its characteristic polynomial $$x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kx^k$$ Let $c_{-1},c_{-2},\dots=0$
Then $$x^{n+1}=\sum c_{k-1}x^k+c_{n-1}\sum c_kx^k$$ $$x^{n+2}=\sum c_{k-2}x^k+(c_{n-1}+c_{n-2})\sum c_{k-1}x^k+c_{n-1}^2\sum c_kx^k$$ $$x^{n+3}=\sum c_{k-3}x^k+(c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}+c_{n-3})\sum c_{k-2}x^k+(c_{n-1}^2+c_{n-1}c_{n-2}+c_{n-2}^2)+\sum c_{k-1}x^k+c_{n-1}^3\sum c_kx^k$$ $$\dots$$
Then add them together: $$x^n+x^{n+1}+x^{n+2}+\dots=\sum c_{k-n+1}x^k+(1+c_1+\dots+c_{n-1}+c_1^2+c_1c_2+\dots+c_2^2+\dots+c_{n-1}^2+\dots)\sum c_{k-n+2}x^k+(1+c_1+c_1c_2+\dots+c_{n-2}+c_1^2+c_1c_2+c_2^2+\dots+c_{n-2}^2+\dots)\sum c_{k-n+3}+\dots+(1+c_1+c_2+c_1^2+c_1c_2+c_2^2+c_1^3+c_1^2c_2+c_1c_2^2+c_2^3+\dots)\sum c_{k-1}x^k+(1+c_1+c_1^2+c_1^3+\dots)\sum c_kx^k$$ by combining it with $1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{n-1}$ and use analytic continutation, we obtain: $$f(x)=\sum (1+\frac{c_{m-n+1+k}}{\prod 1-c_l})x^k$$
